# How to convert string to uppercase in windows textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, uppercase

I've a textbox in my windows application. It allows only alphabets and digits. I want when ever I type any alphabet, it should be converted to uppercase.How can I do that and in which event? I've used str.ToUpper() but the cursor is shifting to the beginning of the string. Please give me solution.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You just need to change CharacterChasing property to `Upper`.

```
textBox1.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper
```

Answer (score 12):

Why to reinvent the wheel, just set 'CharacterCasing' property of textBox to 'Upper'. You don't need to write any code.

[image: Make letters in textBox uppercase]

In case of masked textbox, you can use '>' (in mask property) to make following characters uppercase. e.g. For a input alphanumeric string (A-Z, 0-9) of length eight, use mask '>AAAAAAAA'. To restrict to letters only (A-Z), use '>LLLLLLLL'.

[image: Make letters in maskedTextBox uppercase]

Comment: It should be the best answer!

Answer (score 8):

You need to assign the results of `ToUpper` back to the textbox:

```
txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text.ToUpper();
```

Alternatively, set the [`CharacterCasing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.charactercasing.aspx) property of the textbox to `Upper`:

```
txtBox.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
```

Comment: no,doing so in keypress or keydown or keyup event shifts the cursor at the zero position in the textbox as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Sukanya - Indeed. Which is why you shouldn't do that on those event handlers. You can do this on the `LostFocus` event handler, but need to be careful, but a better solution is to simply set the `CharacterCasing` property.

Answer (score 3):

In properties of TextBox simply set CharacterCasing to Upper. It'll convert all entered character in uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use KeyPress event and the handler should be similar to the following;

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            e.KeyChar= (e.KeyChar.ToString()).ToUpper().ToCharArray()[0];
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void mytextbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)

{

e.KeyChar = Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Right click the TextBox in the Designer, under Properties change CharacterCasing to Upper.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the event: TextBox1_EditValueChanging.

If each time the cursor moves at the first position, you can calculate the number of characters in your txt and shift the cursor after the last charachter.

Answer (score 0):

1. TxtInput        //This is the textbox user inputs
2. LblLengthstrong //Label to show length
3. LblUpper        //Label that shows it in uppercase
4. LblLower        //Label that shows it in lowercase
5. LblRight        //Label that shows shows last 3 characters
6. LblSubscript    //Label that shows characters 1 through 3

**//show length of all characters inputed**

```
 private void BtnLength_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LblLength.Text = TxtInput.Text.Length.ToString();
        }
```

**//make to characters upper**

```
  private void btnUpper_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LblUpper.Text = TxtInput.Text.ToUpper();
        }
```

**//make characters to lowercase**

```
 private void BtnLower_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LblLower.Text = TxtInput.Text.ToLower();
        }
```

**//show last 3 characters**

```
 private void BtnRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LblRight.Text = TxtInput.Text.Substring(TxtInput.Text.Length - 3);
        }
```

**//show characters in position 1 through 3**

```
 private void BtnSubscript_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LblSubscript.Text = TxtInput.Text.Substring(1, 3);
        }
```

**//ASCII**

```
  private void BtnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name;
            int letter;

            name = TxtInput.Text;

            for (int index = 0; index < name.Length; index++)
            {
                letter = name[index];
                MessageBox.Show(letter.ToString());
            }
        }
```

**//Password**

```
      int InNumTry = 0;
    private void BtnGo_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string password;
        password = TxtIn.Text;

            switch (password)
            {
                case " ": MessageBox.Show("Passowrd is empty.");
                    break;

                case "MIKE": MessageBox.Show("Password is OK!");
                    FrmBOO newForm = new FrmBOO();
                    newForm.Show();
                    break;

                default:
                    InNumTry++;
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Passwrod, try again!");
                    TxtIn.Text = "";
                    TxtIn.Focus();
                    break;
            }

            if (InNumTry >= 3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have tried too many times, have a good day.");
                TxtIn.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

**// Adding timer(In the timer add the code under this (Add add timer1.Start(); in the start form)**

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;
            this.LblTime.Text = datetime.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: The response is too long and can confuse the guy who ask. The question is actually clear and request only the event to handle.